# Auto-creation of the tags in VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, tags, webstorm

Only recently have I moved to VSCode from WebStorm and I love it.

One feature still missing for me is in WebStorm when I wanted to create an HTML tag, i.e. `<div></div>` the only thing I would have to do was type "div" and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. This would automatically create me the tag and the closing tag. Was especially useful when creating img tags `<img src=""></img>`. It saved me a hassle to press `<` and `>` every time.

I cannot seem to find this option in VSCode. Anyone?

Comment: emmet expansion is built-in to vscode - you shouldn't have to do anything to get it to work.  What kind of file are you in?

Answer (score 5):

Visual Studio code has built in support for this.

So first of all make sure that you doing this in .html file.

Then, you can check for, `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true` in your settings.json in vscode.

If that does not help, you can checkout this page.

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Also please mark it as accepted if you find it helpful , I am trying build my reputation on stack overflow.